# So once I FaceTimed one of my friends, but this random dude answered

Tags: facetime

So once I tried to face time my friend, but when it connected it was a random dude that I have never met. This has happend to me three times now. Each time it is a different guy. Help, I don't know if it is my account or hers.

Comment: do you use phone or email ?

Comment: You are not alone in experiencing [misdirected FaceTime calls](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4306102?start=0&tstart=0). See [FaceTime calls wrong person](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167551/facetime-calls-wrong-person) and [FaceTime Hijacked](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104884/facetime-hijacked?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The only reason some random person would get your call is if you called the wrong number.

Try verifying your friend's number. Make sure that's the only entry in her contact info. Also try getting the email she has for FaceTime.

I've had it happen to me and the reason was I had a different number listed in my friend's contact info.

Also, is there a chance your friend is just messing with you?